# IronPython disable Import after use

Tags: import, ironpython

Is there any way to disable the use of import once I've finished using it? I'm using IronPython as a scripting engine and I don't want users to be able to import anything. This could be done in LuaInterface by the use of setfenv:

```
luanet.load_assembly("System.Windows.Forms")
luanet.load_assembly("System.Drawing")

Form=luanet.import_type("System.Windows.Forms.Form")

-- Only allow the use of the form class

local env = { Form = _G.Form }

setfenv(1, env)
```

Or by setting the import functions to nil before parsing the script file:

```
luanet.load_assembly = nil
luanet.import_type = nil
```

Is this possible in IronPython?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pre-check the scripts you are executing and disallow any that have `import` statements (or `from ... import` statements).

```
foreach(line in script) {
    if(line.TrimeStart().StartsWith("import") || line.TrimeStart().StartsWith("from") {
        throw ...;
    }
}
```

It's not foolproof (`__import__` is still an issue), but it will cover the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hook to the import function and deal with user import anyway you like.

In you case you can just return null for any import that your hook gets.

It was explained how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127766/448547