# Infinite recursive reference using IronPython

Tags: c#, python, recursion, ironpython

Sorry in advance if this is a dumb question. I'm new to Python in general (not new to other languages at all) and new to IronPython in particular.

I'm trying to run a Python project via my C# project. I'm including all the relevant Python sources as embedded resources (which I read into a `Dictionary<string,string>` where the key is the name of the module and the value is the content of the file.

I've implemented a class quite similar to the one suggested in this reply to "[Custom IronPython import resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127766/619249)", like so:

```
public class PythonInstance
{
    private ScriptEngine engine;
    private ScriptScope scope;
    private ScriptSource source;
    private CompiledCode compiled;
    private object pythonClass;
    private delegate object ImportDelegate(CodeContext context, string moduleName, PythonDictionary globals, PythonDictionary locals, PythonTuple tuple);
    private Dictionary<string, string> importModulesCode = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public PythonInstance(string code, Dictionary<string,string> modulesCode, string className = "PyClass")
    {
        this.importModulesCode.Clear();
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> module in modulesCode)
            this.importModulesCode.Add(module.Key, module.Value);

        //creating engine and stuff
        this.engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        this.scope = Python.GetBuiltinModule(engine);//engine.CreateScope();

        this.scope.SetVariable("__import__", new ImportDelegate(this.ImportModuleFromResources));

        //loading and compiling code
        this.source = this.engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
        this.compiled = this.source.Compile();

        //now executing this code (the code should contain a class)
        this.compiled.Execute(this.scope);

        //now creating an object that could be used to access the stuff inside a python script
        this.pythonClass = this.engine.Operations.Invoke(this.scope.GetVariable(className));
    }

    public void SetVariable(string variable, dynamic value)
    {
        this.scope.SetVariable(variable, value);
    }

    public dynamic GetVariable(string variable)
    {
        return this.scope.GetVariable(variable);
    }

    public void CallMethod(string method, params dynamic[] arguments)
    {
        this.engine.Operations.InvokeMember(this.pythonClass, method, arguments);
    }

    public dynamic CallFunction(string method, params dynamic[] arguments)
    {
        return this.engine.Operations.InvokeMember(this.pythonClass, method, arguments);
    }

    protected object ImportModuleFromResources(CodeContext context, string moduleName, PythonDictionary globals, PythonDictionary locals, PythonTuple tuple)
    {
        if ((this.importModulesCode.Keys.Contains(moduleName)) && (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.importModulesCode[moduleName])))
        {
            string rawScript = this.importModulesCode[moduleName];
            this.engine.Execute(rawScript, this.scope);
            Scope ret = HostingHelpers.GetScope(this.scope);
            this.scope.SetVariable(moduleName, ret);
            return ret;
        }
        else
        {   // fall back on the built-in method
            return Builtin.__import__(context, moduleName);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this seems to work fine. Just that I'm getting a stack overflow exception when I try to run the Python code, since the references seem to be recursive.

My main pyw file contains the following header:

```
import os, sys, getopt, __builtin__
from pyglossary.glossary import confPath, VERSION
```

The first import is of the `os` module, which I've taken out of the IronPython Lib, so my `ImportModuleFromResources` method uses the first `if` block and the reference gets resolved.

The next iteration tries to import `sys` (using the `else` block and the built-in module import), then `errno` (again the `else` block and the built-in module import) -> `nt` (built-in import again) -> `nt` (again..) -> `ntpath` (yep..) -> then going back to `os` again, and continues in an infinite recursion to go through the modules again... (resulting in a stack overflow, of course).

Since I'm no Python expert, and I am not aware of IronPython's standard library modules and how they refer to each other, I'm sure I'm doing something very basic wrong, but not sure which reference I need to take out, manipulate one of my included Lib files (unlikely, I think), or improve my `ImportModuleFromResources` method in order to avoid a recursive reference..

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have done it the same way like [Einar Egilsson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4644585/1083111) has sugested in [Custom IronPython import resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105804/custom-ironpython-import-resolution/4127766#4127766) => Use a `PlatformAdaptationLayer`

In this way, ironpython uses its own mechanisms to search for modules and only uses your code when a module can't be found.