# Overriding python import mechanism

Tags: python, import, package, ironpython

Currently i try to implement my own mechanism for importing (Iron)Python files, but i'm note sure, if i'm consedering all cases.

For example i have the current structure in the filesystem for thesting the system:

```
/Sample/
    /ImportResolver/
        /Math/
            /__init__.py
            /Math2.py
```

**__init__py** contains:

```
# Sample math package
import Math2
```

**Math.py** contains:

```
# Add two values
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Now if i execute the following import statement:

```
import Sample.ImportResolver.Math
```

My code tries to resolve the following python scripts, when importing:

> Try import sub package: Sample/**init**.py
>   Try import sub package: Sample/ImportResolver/**init**.py
>   Try import module:      Sample/ImportResolver/Math.py
>   Try import package:     Sample/ImportResolver/Math/**init**.py

Looking at the list above, am i trying to import all things needed, or is the mecahnism completly wrong?

Furthermore, which files should the importer try to import when executing:

```
from Sample.ImportResolver import Math
```

Please tell me if it is totally unclear what i am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Why would you reimplement a core part of the Python language? Do you have some special requirements for how `import` should work? If so, how can we possibly know whether your code is correct? You haven't specified your custom behaviour.

Comment: My custom behaviour is to provide a kind of import resolver, to import scripts from databases, web services and so on.

Comment: @BendEg, have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34117632/468244) ? Does that help you out? You would just build on top of the existing infrastructure instead of replacing it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this helps. I take a look at `path_hooks`, this seems to be the best way for completly custom importer...